# How to create and subscribe to a kotlin Flow, but start emitting later

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to create a reactive Flow for refreshing login token in a loop when the view is in the foreground, but refreshing should **start later** after certain conditions are met (user has logged in for example) and obviously stop when the view is hidden.

a simple approach without the "*start later/checking condition*" part would be something like this:

```
RefreshTokenUseCase.kt:

suspend fun tokenRefresh(): Flow<RefreshResult> = flow {
    while (true) {
        delay(5000)
        val res = refreshToken(userToken)
        emit(res)
    }
}
```

then in the view model, I would filter the result for errors

```
SomeViewModel.kt:
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val loggedOutError = refreshTokenUseCase.tokenRefresh().filter { it == TokenExpired) }
}
```

then in the view, I would collect those changes:

```
SomeFragment.kt:

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.loggedOutError.collect {
            showLoggedOutError()
        }
    }
}
```

But above would result in refreshing right away which is not what I want.

I would like the refreshing to be paused in the beginning and then add something like this:

```
SomeViewModel.kt:
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    (...)
    fun userHasLoggedIn() {
        startRefreshing() // <- how to implement this?
    }
}
```

How would you approach it, having in mind a clean architecture / reactive style of coding?

Comment: Where do you trigger `tokenRefresh()`?

Comment: @Zain tokenRefresh is used in view model shown above `refreshTokenUseCase.refreshToken().filter {...}`
Edit: actually I see there's a spelling error, it supposed to be the same name ;-) edited original src

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of `SharedFlow`.
Different than regular `Flow`, `SharedFlow` is a *hot flow*. It allows you to send updates to the `Flow` at runtime.
To achieve your desired behavior you could make use of the `combine` operator, combining the *cold flow* of token refresh and the *hot flow* for the logged in state.
See here a minimal code example:

ViewModel:

```
const val TAG = "CoroutineDemo"

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private suspend fun tokenRefresh() = flow {
        var i = 0
        while (true) {
            delay(5000)
            emit(i++)
        }
    }

    private val readyToLogin: MutableSharedFlow<Boolean> = MutableSharedFlow()

    fun setReadyToLogin(ready: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        readyToLogin.emit(ready)
    }

    suspend fun tokenRefreshWhenReady(): Flow<Int> = readyToLogin
        .combine(tokenRefresh()) { readyToLogin: Boolean, token: Int ->
            readyToLogin to token
        }.filter { it.first } // only emit if readyToLogin=true
        .map { it.second } // only return the token, but not logged in state

}
```

Fragment:

```
 class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            Log.d(TAG, "App started")
            viewModel.tokenRefreshWhenReady().collect { value: Int ->
                Log.d(TAG, "Update: $value")
            }
        }

        requireActivity().findViewById<Button>(R.id.login).setOnClickListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Logged in")
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.setReadyToLogin(true)
            }
        }

        requireActivity().findViewById<Button>(R.id.logout).setOnClickListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Logged out")
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.setReadyToLogin(false)
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

It works as follows citing the logs:

*App started*

then nothing happens until you press the login button (just for demo purposes).

*Logged in*

now after every 5 seconds you get updates like

*Update: 5*

*Update: 6*

*Update: 7*

etc.

if you press the logout button (just for demo purposes)

*Logged out*

and the output stops

**Technical explanation:**
The login button click sets the hot flow (`readyToLogin`) to true so that `tokenRefreshWhenReady` emits the latest token. If you press logout the hot flow is set to `false` and the token is no longer emited.

Comment: Michael, thanks for great input, I tried your approach, it makes the loop run in the background for the whole time. I also miss canceling the loop/network coroutine when the condition goes to false (e.g. user logged out in this example). Any ideas? for now I've ended up with a simple coroutine loop run and stopped manually, not much reactive style

Comment: Sorry, it was my understanding that you want to let the checks run while the app is in foreground? Or do you mean it's also running when the app is in background? That was because in my demo I didn't use launchWhenStarted. That's now fixed. The updated version also doesn't emit no longer if the user is logged out